# Error in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql

I am getting the following error when I execute my stored procedure:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near '2011'.
> (1 row(s) affected)

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeliveryFileNames]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)

    Create Table #DelivTemp(
        Style nvarchar(50),
        Material nvarchar(50),
        Filename nvarchar(100),
        delivered_date date)

    set @SQL=
    N'insert into #DelivTemp
    Select distinct Style,Material,filename 
    from OPENQUERY(GCS_PRODUCTION,
    ''SELECT LEFT(FILENAME,locate(''''_'''',FILENAME)-1)as Style,
        substring_index(filename,''''_'''',2)as Material,filename,
        delivered_date FROM view_delivery_log
        where delivered_date > ''2011%'' order by Style '')'

    exec (@SQL)

    drop table dbo.DelivFN

    Select * into dbo.DelivFN
    from #DelivTemp

END
```

I am using OpenQuery to update a SQL table from a linked server on SQL Server 2008 R2.

I know that the underscore is a real issue, but I have tried a plethora of options including `\`, `%` and both single and double quotes.

Regardless I am getting the same result. I can run the query independently of the stored procedure and achieve the correct results. The filename field referenced several times is formatted `00000000_ABC4_A.png`.  I am using the underscore to identify the components of the file name that I need for my reporting purposes.

Comment: Your #temp table has 4 columns yet your insert statement only has 3. So once you fix the parsing issue you'll then get an error on the insert. You need to either explicitly add a value for the date column, set a default value for it, or use a proper column list on the insert and leave it out.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the the logical error of your date comparison using the `%` that the others have pointed out, your current issue is a syntactical error.

Since you've got a dynamic sql statement contained within another dynamic sql statement... you'll need to *double-escape* all of your single quotes... which you did in most of the query, except for the following line:

```
where delivered_date > ''2011%'' order by Style '')'
```

Properly escaped, would be:

```
where delivered_date > ''''2011%'''' order by Style '')'
```

Which raises the question... why are you building up the string to execute dynamically, instead of just calling the statement directly?

Comment: As stated above there is something which has caused a great deal of problems when I run it with the fqn.  This has worked well in the past.

Answer (score 1):

It's the syntax of ''2011%''.  This is not a valid date.  % being a wildcard means the compiler can't know what to compare against in the WHERE clause.  You'd need to use an actual date: i.e. ''2011_01_01'' so the compiler can know what to compare against

Comment: What if `delivered_date` is not a date/datetime column, but varchar?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the stored proc `exec` runs under a different session, therefore you won't have access to the temp table anyway. So, it won't matter if you get that sql statement to run.  You could always use `YEAR(delivered_date) > 2011`.

Another approach would be to use the fqn for the linked server to select into and bypass the temp table all together:

```
SELECT LEFT(FILENAME,locate('_',FILENAME)-1)as Style,
    substring_index(filename,'_',2)as Material,filename,delivered_date 
FROM [linked_server_name].[db_name].[dbo].view_delivery_log
into dbo.DelivFN
```

Comment: I actually tried that initially and was getting errors.  I have used this approach on other stored procedures and it has worked very well.  I agree on the date.  Your code is the proper way to execute.  I will incorporate the change.